# RNG Minigame In Python - Best Practices & Possible Improvements?

Tags: python, number-guessing-game

Recently, I got into programming with Python as a fun little side hobby. After watching a bunch of YouTube tutorials (to learn about IDE's, variables, etc.), I finally got to the point where I was able to make this really simple game where the player tries to guess the number that the computer generated. So, today I was hoping to get some feedback on the code I wrote.

I'm mostly interested in learning about the best practices for this language, but any criticism is welcome:

**player.py**

```
class Player:

    def __init__(self):
        """Initializes the player object's attributes."""
        self.username = "Player_1"
        self.guess = None
        self.wins = 0

    def create_username(self):
        """Prompts the player to enter their username."""
        self.username = input("What is your name?: ")

    def get_username(self):
        """Returns the player's username as a string."""
        return self.username
    
    def get_guess(self):
        """Returns the player's guess as an integer."""

        is_valid_input = False

        while not is_valid_input:
            
            try:
                self.guess = int(input("Can you guess what it is?: "))
                is_valid_input = True
                return self.guess
            
            except ValueError:
                print()
                print("Please enter a whole number.")

    def add_win(self):
        """Adds a win to the player's win count."""
        self.wins += 1

    def get_wins(self):
        """Returns the player's win count as a string."""
        return str(self.wins)
```

**random_number_guesser.py**

```
from player import Player
import random

class Random_Number_Guesser:

    def __init__(self):
        """Initializes the game object's attributes."""
        self.player = None
        self.winning_number = None

    def create_player(self):
        """Creates a new player object."""
        self.player = Player()
        self.player.create_username()

    def greet_player(self):
        """Greets the player."""
        print("Welcome, " + self.player.get_username() + "!")

    def generate_random_number(self):
        """Generates a winning number."""
        self.winning_number = random.randint(1, 10)
        print()
        print("The winning number is: " + str(self.winning_number) + ".")
        print("I'm thinking of a number between 1 & 10.")
        
    def guess_and_check(self):
        """Compares the player's guess to the winning number."""
        
        # Checks if the player's guess is correct.
        if self.player.get_guess() == self.winning_number:
            print()
            print(self.player.get_username() + " Won!")
            self.player.add_win()
        else:
            print()
            print(self.player.get_username() + " Lost!")

    def play_again(self):
        """Determines whether or not the player wants to play again."""

        is_finished_playing = False

        while not is_finished_playing:

            play_again = input("Would you like to play again? (y/n): ")

            # Checks if the player wants to play again & handles invalid inputs.
            if play_again == "y":
                self.generate_random_number()
                self.guess_and_check()

            elif play_again == "n":
                print()
                # Checks the player's win count and determines if 'time' or 'times' should be used.
                if int(self.player.get_wins()) > 1 or int(self.player.get_wins()) == 0:
                    print(self.player.get_username() + " won " + self.player.get_wins() + " times!")
                else:
                    print(self.player.get_username() + " won " + self.player.get_wins() + " time!")
                break

            else:
                print()
                print("Please enter either 'y' or 'n'.")

def play_random_number_guesser():
    print("Welcome To Random Number Guesser!")
    print("=================================")

    game = Random_Number_Guesser()
    game.create_player()
    game.greet_player()
    game.generate_random_number()
    game.guess_and_check()
    game.play_again()
```

**game.py**

```
from random_number_guesser import *

if __name__ == "__main__":
    play_random_number_guesser()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a good start.

### The good

You've avoided global variables.

You've written properly-formatted docstrings.

You have multiple modules (fancy!)

You have some input validation.

You have a correctly-defined `__main__` guard and top-level method.

Broadly, the code does seem to function as intended.

### The bad

`username` mutates, when it shouldn't need to - it can be passed into the constructor and then never changed. Decreasing member mutation will create more provably-correct and more easily-testable code.

Do not store `self.guess` as a member.

Add type hints. In this case, since you have very few functions that accept arguments or return values, almost everything is `None`.

It's conventional for Python class members to be accessed directly instead of through getters, so delete `get_username` etc.

`get_username` in particular is better represented as a `__str__` method so that you can write the likes of `print(player)` and it will do the right thing.

You need to get out of the habit of writing unnecessary loop variables such as `is_valid_input`. Many such variables can be replaced with a simple `break` when the time comes.

Since this is in theory a game, you should delete your `The winning number is:` debug statement.

`generate_random_number` only needs to be called from one place in this program - in the middle of the `play_again` loop.

In that `play_again` method, you actually need *two* loops - an outer loop for the game, and an inner loop for input validation.

Your plural check can be simplified by checking for equality with 1.

1 and 10 should not be hard-coded; move them to class member variables or statics.

### The ugly

Don't add underscores to your class names; PEP8 asks for UpperCamelCase.

### Suggested

Certainly other things to improve, but this is a start:

```py
import random


class Player:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        """Initializes the player object's attributes."""
        self.username = "Player_1"
        self.wins = 0

    def create_username(self) -> None:
        """Prompts the player to enter their username."""
        self.username = input("What is your name?: ")

    def get_guess(self) -> int:
        """Gets the player's guess as an integer."""
        while True:
            try:
                return int(input("Can you guess what it is?: "))
            except ValueError:
                print("Please enter a whole number.")

    def add_win(self) -> None:
        """Adds a win to the player's win count."""
        self.wins += 1

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.username


class RandomNumberGuesser:
    MIN = 1
    MAX = 10

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        """Initializes the game object's attributes."""
        self.player: Player | None = None
        self.winning_number: int | None = None

    def create_player(self) -> None:
        """Creates a new player object."""
        self.player = Player()
        self.player.create_username()

    def greet_player(self) -> None:
        """Greets the player."""
        print(f"Welcome, {self.player}!")

    def generate_random_number(self) -> None:
        """Generates a winning number."""
        self.winning_number = random.randint(self.MIN, self.MAX)

        # Debug only
        # print(f"The winning number is: {self.winning_number}.")

        print(f"I'm thinking of a number between {self.MIN} & {self.MAX}.")

    def guess_and_check(self) -> None:
        """Compares the player's guess to the winning number."""

        # Checks if the player's guess is correct.
        if self.player.get_guess() == self.winning_number:
            print(f'{self.player} Won!')
            self.player.add_win()
        else:
            print(f'{self.player} Lost!')

    def play_loop(self) -> None:
        """Determines whether the player wants to play again."""

        while True:
            print()
            self.generate_random_number()
            self.guess_and_check()

            while True:
                play_again = input("Would you like to play again? (y|n): ")

                # Checks if the player wants to play again & handles invalid inputs.
                if play_again == "y":
                    break

                elif play_again == "n":
                    print()

                    # Checks the player's win count and determines if 'time' or 'times' should be used.
                    if self.player.wins == 1:
                        print(f'{self.player} won one time!')
                    else:
                        print(f'{self.player} won {self.player.wins} times!')
                    return

                else:
                    print("Please enter either 'y' or 'n'.")


def play_random_number_guesser() -> None:
    print("Welcome To Random Number Guesser!")
    print("=================================")

    game = RandomNumberGuesser()
    game.create_player()
    game.greet_player()
    game.play_loop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    play_random_number_guesser()
```

```
Welcome To Random Number Guesser!
=================================
What is your name?: me
Welcome, me!

I'm thinking of a number between 1 & 10.
Can you guess what it is?: 2
me Lost!
Would you like to play again? (y|n): y

I'm thinking of a number between 1 & 10.
Can you guess what it is?: 3
me Lost!
Would you like to play again? (y|n): n

me won 0 times!
```